# Error C2011 '_iobuf': 'struct' type redefinition

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have problems with my code, after including dirent.h in my project, I got the error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C2011   '_iobuf': 'struct' type redefinition    KittenProject   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h   26

in the corecrt_wstdio.h file, line 26

how can I fix this? thanks in advence

Comment: Please post a [mcve]